# Number of functions having $n$ values such that $f(x) = x$

Tags: combinatorics

The problem is to find the number of functions $f:\lbrace x_1, \cdots, x_N \rbrace \rightarrow  \lbrace x_1, \cdots, x_N \rbrace$ having exactly $n$ values that satisfy $f(x) = x$. Let $D(X \geq n)$ represent the number of functions having exactly $n$ or more values that satisfy $f(x) =x$. Then,

$$ \begin{align}
D_n &= D(X \geq n) - D(X \geq n+1) \\
\end{align}$$

$D(X \geq n)$ is the number of ways to choose at least $n$ items to satisfy $f(x) = x$, and map  rest of the domain randomly, so $D(X \geq n) = {N \choose n}(N-n)!=N!/n!$. Therefore,

$$
D_n = N!\left[ \frac{1}{n!} - \frac{1}{(n+1)!} \right]$$

Why is this solution wrong?

Comment: Oh what a foolish mistake. Thank you, I will go fix my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be
$$D_n = {N \choose n}\color{blue}{(N-1)^{N-n}}$$
because after picking the $n$ fixed points, each of the other $N-n$ entries can be chosen in $N-1$ ways.